# How to set group name in DevExpress Collectionview in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, devexpress

I followed [this](https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/DevExpress.XamarinForms.CollectionView.DXCollectionView) documentation and I got some progress. But I can not set group header name that I want.

In tutorials and documentations people add this group name from MenuGroup name but I can not.

This is my code:

```
MenuGroupList.Add(new MenuGroup("Raporlar",new[] { fPage }));
```

I want that `Raporlar` as a group header. I tried so many things and found no solution yet.

[image]

My classes:

```
public class MenuGroup : ObservableCollection<FlyoutItemPage>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public MenuGroup(string name) : base()
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public MenuGroup(string name, IEnumerable<FlyoutItemPage> collection) : base(collection)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class FlyoutItemPage
{
    public FlyoutItemPage(int pageID, string title, Type targetPage, string iconSource, string grup, string programkod)
    {
        this.PageID = pageID;
        this.TargetPage = targetPage;
        this.Title = title;
        this.IconSource = iconSource;
        this.Grup = grup;
        this.PROGRAMKOD = programkod;   
    }

    public int PageID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type TargetPage { get; set; }

    public string Grup {get; set;}
    public string IconSource { get; set; }
    public string PROGRAMKOD { get; set; }
}
```

View model:

```
private ObservableCollection<MenuGroup> _menuGroupList;

public ObservableCollection<MenuGroup> MenuGroupList
{
    get
    {
        if (_menuGroupList == null)
            _menuGroupList = new ObservableCollection<MenuGroup>();

        return _menuGroupList;
    }
    set { _menuGroupList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}

FlyoutItemPage fPage = new FlyoutItemPage(i, yetkiList[i].BASLIK, typeof(RaporSecimPage), "@drawable/delivery.png", yetkiList[i].GRUP, yetkiList[i].PROGRAMKOD);

MenuGroupList.Add(new MenuGroup("Raporlar", new[] { fPage }));
```

XAML:

```
<StackLayout WidthRequest="250" HorizontalOptions="Start"  BackgroundColor="#93EDC7">
        <Image Source="@drawable/ida_logo" Margin="20"/>
        <!-- Collectionview -->
        <!--ItemTapped="menuPopUpPagesList_ItemTapped"-->
        <dxcv:DXCollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuPageList}"    DisplayMember="Title">
            <dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding GotoOtherPageCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MenuPagePopUpViewModel}} }" 
                            xct:TouchEffect.CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            xct:TouchEffect.LongPressCommand="{Binding OnLongPressCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MenuPagePopUpViewModel}}}"
                            xct:TouchEffect.LongPressCommandParameter="{Binding .}" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0,2" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <!--Group items.-->
            <dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupDescription>
                <dxcv:GroupDescription FieldName="Grup"   GroupInterval="Value"/>
            </dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupDescription>

            <!--Define the group header template.-->
            <dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Margin="3" BackgroundColor="LightGray" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label FontFamily="Roboto" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                        <Image Source="@drawable/popupmenu.png"  HeightRequest="20" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        </dxcv:DXCollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [official doc](https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/402076/xamarin-forms/collection-view/getting-started/lesson-1-data) and [sample](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/xamarin-forms-collection-view-examples/blob/21.1.3%2B/CS/GettingStarted/CollectionViewExample/ViewModel.cs), you don't have to create a collection like your **MenuGroup**. The way you use to group data is for Xamarin Forms CollectionView. DevExpress is different though.

1.If you want to group the data based on the **Grup** property value, and display it as the group header, as you did in the code

```
<dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupDescription>
            <dxcv:GroupDescription FieldName="Grup"   GroupInterval="Value"/>
</dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupDescription>
```

you just have to create a

```
public ObservableCollection<FlyoutItemPage> FlyoutItemPages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FlyoutItemPage>();
```

and use data bindings for itemsSource

```
<dxcv:DXCollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding FlyoutItemPages}"
```

2.If **Grup** value is not the value you want to display in header, then you could define a new **Group** property in **FlyoutItemPage** class.

```
public class FlyoutItemPage
{
    ...
    public string Group { get; set; }
}
```

And use **Group** value as header

```
<dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupDescription>
            <dxcv:GroupDescription FieldName="Group"   GroupInterval="Value"/>
</dxcv:DXCollectionView.GroupDescription>
```

Also create and bind to this collection,

```
public ObservableCollection<FlyoutItemPage> FlyoutItemPages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FlyoutItemPage>();
```

Don't forget to set the Group value of each items when adding them to the collection.

Comment: It seems I need a new parameter like "MenuGroup". I'm looking a solution from yesterday but I couln't find yet. I talked with other developer frined who develop backend of my application. We decided to make a new parameter to group our menus. Benefits : 1 menu group wont be hard code, 2 it can change anytime without app update, 3. we can mix menus "goods" and "reports.

Comment: Yeah, that seems a good idea!